# Unable to connect Docker Container using HttpURLConnection in Java

Tags: java, docker, httpurlconnection

I have created two Web Projects in java.
One of the project was running inside the Tomcat docker container:

```
192.160.1.5:8080/SocketServer
```

Another project was running in local machine using eclipse

```
localhost:8081/SocketClient
```

I am trying to connect the SocketServer project running inside docker container from the SocketClient using HttpURLConnection in java. But it gives some errors like below:

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:574)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:563)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.connect(NioSocketImpl.java:588)
    at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:333)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:648)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:597)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:520)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:370)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.protocol.DefaultProtocolSocketFactory.createSocket(DefaultProtocolSocketFactory.java:80)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.protocol.DefaultProtocolSocketFactory.createSocket(DefaultProtocolSocketFactory.java:122)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpConnection.open(HttpConnection.java:707)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeWithRetry(HttpMethodDirector.java:387)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeMethod(HttpMethodDirector.java:171)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:397)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:323)
    at com.dump.LogAction.startSocket(LogAction.java:61)
    at com.dump.LogAction.execute(LogAction.java:37)
```

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score -1):

This is normal behavior, you should read the docs.
https://docs.docker.com/network/network-tutorial-host/

Quick answer: run the docker image with `--network host` argument **OR** you need to expose a port publicly https://www.whitesourcesoftware.com/free-developer-tools/blog/docker-expose-port/ `--expose 8080`